# Insert a separator using this WordPress PHP plugin code

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help with modifying the below PHP. Essentially I need to insert a separator in the output between $time & $Venue and turn the venue into a hyperlink with a fixed URL.

```
if (! function_exists('TCG_eventbrite_event_meta')) :

    function TCG_eventbrite_event_meta() {
        // Determine our separator.
        $separator = apply_filters('eventbrite_meta_separator', '<span class="sep"> &middot; </span>');
        // Start our HTML output with the event time.
        $time = '<span class="event-time">' . eventbrite_event_time() . '</span>';
        // Add a venue name if available.
        $venue = '<span class="event-venue">' . eventbrite_event_venue()->name . '</span>';
        // Assemble our HTML. Yugly.
        $html = sprintf(_x( '%1$s%2$s', '%1$s: time, %2$s: venue', 'eventbrite-api'),
            $time,
            $venue
        );
        echo apply_filters('eventbrite_event_meta', $html, $time, $venue);
    }
endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest solution is this:

```
$venue = ' | <span class="event-venue"><a href="http//staticlink.com" target="_blank">' . eventbrite_event_venue()->name . '</a></span>';
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, TY